# C# Can't access base properties of a class (only inherited)

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, visual-studio-2012, properties

Here is my code (should be easy to understand what I'm trying to achieve):

```
public class Order
{
    private Drink drink;
    public Drink Drink {get { return drink; } set { drink = value; }}
}

public class Drink
{
    enum colour 
    {
        Red, Transparent
    };
}

public class cocktail : Drink
{
    private int alcoholContent;
    public int AlcoholContent  { get { return alcoholContent; } set { alcoholContent = value; } }
}
```

And then I'm trying to access the properties, but they aren't there:

```
Order order = new Order();
order.Drink = new cocktail();
order.Drink. <- no alcohol content?
```

Why is that? I thought I did create a cocktail class, not just a Drink?
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Because Drink doesn't expose an AlcoholContent property - cocktail does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use `AlcoholContent` property directly, because you're using `Coctail` instance through `Drink` reference.

```
Order order = new Order();
order.Drink = new cocktail();
//  order.Drink. <- no alcohol content?
((Coctail)order.Drink).AlcoholContent <- works just fine
```

You have to use explicit `(Coctail)` cast to use members specific to `Coctail` class.

Why is that? Consider a situation, where there is another class named `SoftDrink`:

```
public class SoftDrink : Drink
{
}
```

You'd still be able to assign `SoftDrink` instance to `order.Drink`:

```
Order order = new Order();
order.Drink = new SoftDrink();
//  order.Drink. <- no alcohol content? It's a SoftDring!!
```

And because `order.Drink` property can handle **every** `Drink`, you can only use members specified for `Drink` class. Even if there is really a more specific class instance assigned to that property.

Comment: Hmm how about a `VirginCubaLibre : Drink`? I think it should return 0 for alcohol content.. and `SoftDrink` would be more of a `Beverage`, itself implemented by `Drink` but also by `AppleJuice` :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to distinguish between the actual type and the declared type. In your case, although you instantiate a `cocktail`, you are referencing it as a `Drink`, which does not expose any properties.

To access the properties defined in the `cocktail` class, you need to type-cast your reference:

```
((cocktail)order.Drink).AlcoholContent = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get concrete class properties then should have to explicitly cast to concrete type.

(order.Drink as Cocktail).AlcoholC ontent <- works just fine

Or

You can keep a virtual property as Alcoholicontent in Drink class and override it in        cocktail class. Then you can access those properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast it. Try:

```
Order order = new Order();
order.Drink = new cocktail();
(order.Drink as cocktail).AlcoholContent = 0 ; // please dont drink
```